# Issue between web service client Weblogic 12.2.1 and publisher Weblogic 12.1.2

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

We're facing a integration problem between our newer Weblogic (12.2.1), where we have a client jax-ws, and the publisher (Weblogic 12.1.3).

My webservice client (WL 12.2.1) call a webservice published on WL 12.1.3 but we are getting this error:

**javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Old format work area header is disabled.**

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Old format work area header is disabled.
  at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.workcontext.WorkContextClientTube.processResponse(WorkContextClientTube.java: 61)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java: 1147)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java: 1050)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java: 1019)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java: 877)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java: 463)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java: 191)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java: 108)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java: 92)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java: 161)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy948.consulta(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java: 62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java: 43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 497)
  at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java: 147)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy949.consulta(Unknown Source)
```

We intercept the envelope request (**through Eclipse TCP/IP Monitor**) that we was sending and we seen the header block below:

```xml
<S:Header>
    <WorkContext xmlns="http://oracle.com/weblogic/soap/workarea/">rO0ABXdUABh3ZWJsb2dpYy5hcHAud3NhdXRlbnRpY2EAAADWAAAAI3dlYmxvZ2ljLndvcmthcmVhLlN0cmluZ1dvcmtDb250ZXh0AAsxLjIuMTUtMDAzMQAA</WorkContext>
</S:Header>
```

Manipulating the WorkContextMap we can clean up and don't send the header block:

```java
public static void cleanUpWorkContext() {
    try {
        WorkContextMap rc = (WorkContextMap)
        new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/WorkContextMap");

        if (rc != null) {
            ArrayList < String > lista_para_remover = new ArrayList < String > ();
            if (rc.keys() != null) {
                for (Iterator < String > keys = rc.keys(); keys.hasNext();) {
                    String s = (String) keys.next();
                    log.info("Found " + s + " - " + rc.get(s));
                    if (s.startsWith("weblogic.app")) {
                        log.info("Removing " + s);
                        lista_para_remover.add(s);
                    }

                }

                for (Iterator < String > iterator = lista_para_remover.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    String string = (String) iterator.next();
                    rc.remove(string);
                }
            }
        }
        log.info("RC IS NULL? " + (rc == null));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception: ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After cleaning up the work context and sending a envelope without header we still getting the same error (**Old format...**)

And through Eclipse TCP/IP Monitor we can see the envelope response that looks like:

```xml
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<env:Header xmlns:work="http://bea.com/2004/06/soap/workarea/">
    <work:WorkContext xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
        <java class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
            <string>weblogic.app.sgrcioaiaws</string>
            <int>214</int>
            <string>weblogic.workarea.StringWorkContext</string>
            <string>20170504054331.0</string>
            <string>weblogic.app.eori</string>
            <int>214</int>
            <string>weblogic.workarea.StringWorkContext</string>
            <string>20170530052023.0</string>
            <string/>
        </java>
    </work:WorkContext>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
    <m:consultaResponse xmlns:m="http://xpto">
        <m:ConsultaResponse>
            <java:Object xmlns:java="java:com.xpto" xmlns:n3="java:com.xpto">
                ... some data...
            </java:Object>
        </m:ConsultaResponse>
    </m:consultaResponse>
</env:Body>
```

But after this (by some reason????) we're getting the "Old format..." exception.

The problem could be the header response block? Perhaps this block version (**xmlns:work="http://bea.com/2004/06/soap/workarea/"**) is not acceptable by newer Weblogic's, like our 12.2.1 version?

Thanks for your attention, guys.

**ps: We don't get this error if invoke the webservice through a simple java app or soapUI, only when a call is through a code deployed on WL 12.2.1.**

**Update (weblogic-application.xml)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.4/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <xml>
        <parser-factory>
            <saxparser-factory>org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl</saxparser-factory>
            <document-builder-factory>weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicDocumentBuilderFactory</document-builder-factory>
            <transformer-factory>org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl</transformer-factory>
        </parser-factory>
    </xml>
    <application-param>
        <param-name>webapp.encoding.default</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </application-param>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.xerces.parsers.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.xalan.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

Comment: the issue most likely in weblogic's xml parser/soap jar files being newer on your new server and generating xml old server doesn't have spec on. best best might be to try editing ejb xml to use jars in your war/ear jars to override any the server has built in if possible with <prefer-application-resources> tag

Comment: Hi, @user18896654353, I inserted an update with weblogic-application.xml. Is something like this?

Comment: correct,     <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>package.names.here.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>

Comment: I had already done that but I still have the error.